# is vs Equals() vs == in Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Seems in C#7 we got a new pattern matching mechanic.

As outlined in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/) you can use the `is` keyword to check if a variable has a certain value.

As far as I know before that `is` was used to check type, not content.

So I am wondering - what are the advantages of using `is` in pattern matching, rather than `==` or `Equals()` when checking if a variable has a certain value?

Comment: I think you already answered your own question.

Comment: That article has it pretty well mapped out, what else do you need to know?

Comment: @TheGeneral and Kenneth K. maybe I missed something but from the article I don't see why we use `is` instead of the alternatives. Would it be absolutely the same if in all the code in the article we replaced `is` with `==` or `Equals()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally **is** operator was used to test if an instance is of a certain type or base type. (Although **as** was preferred due to conciseness)

```
class Shape {}
class Circle : Shape {}

var s = new Shape();
var c = new Circle();
Shape nullShape = null;

var isCaCircle = c is Circle; // -> true
var isSaCircle = s is Circle; // -> false
var isCaShape = c is Shape; // -> true
var isNullShapeNull = nullShape is null; // -> true;
```

Knowing this, is more intuitive to use this in a pattern matching expression like:

```
if (c is Shape s) { 
     // use s of type Shape here 
}
```

I think **is** was chosen due to being closer to pattern matching needs and expressing intent better than **==** which can do either reference checking or equality checking, but not polymorphic type compatibility checking.

On a different note, it was more feasible to extend **is** to perform equality than to extend **==** to perform polymorphic type compatibility (for pattern matching purposes).